# Unreal Engine 4.20.1 VR Preview Greyed Out

Tags: unreal-engine4, htc-vive

As title says, the VR Preview option from the play menu is greyed out. I am using the Vive Pro and SteamVR.

Things I have checked:

- Vive Pro devices' firmware are all updated.
- I am using SteamVR beta and it is updated.
- I made sure the Vive Pro were connected by testing them in SteamVR Home.
- I have disabled SteamVR Home before launching Unreal Engine
- I have tried both the UE4's VR template and a empty game (Blank template, 
  Mobile, Scalable, No Starter Content).
- I have double checked that the SteamVR plugin is enabled.
- SteamVR window says Ready and all 5 devices are green.

Computer Specs:

OS: Windows 10
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
RAM: 16GB
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080

Additional notes:

- I have packaged the VR template and ran it. The headset does not rotate camera 
  but the controllers would still teleport me.
- vr.bEnable Stereo 1 does not do anything, at least visibly.

Comment: Did you try with the previous version 4.20 to see if its definatly an issue with .1 or not?

Comment: Apparently the issue fixed itself, despite restarting Unreal and the PC before.